# Grouping different routes within same controller with swagger on NestJs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have an application that has multiple controllers that those controllers have within them 2 routes `@Controller(['1/:someParam', '/2/:someParam'])` but when I create swagger it shows both of them within the same group, what I need is to be able to group those as well.

Is there any possible way to create such a thing?

Comment: I don't think this is feasiable. The grouping from swagger ui is created by `@ApiTags()` (class decorator)

Comment: I did that but it groups route 1 and route 2 in same tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ApiTags**.
@ApiTags('firsturl', 'secondurl')
ApiTags accept string array as parameter.